# "find" command has been looking for mysqli.so for 9.729 hours

Tags: linux, debian, mysql

I have been searching on this site and many others, but I have a process which has been running for 9,729 hours at 100% CPU at all times.  According to htop, this is the command is being run by "root" on my Debian Jessie web server:

```
find ./ -name mysqli.so -print
```

I cannot figure out what is causing the command to run, and issuing a "kill -9" to its PID has no effect.

Everything else seems to run as expected--as evidenced by my not even realizing that this was an issue for so long.  But, since it is busying an entire CPU core at all times, I'd like to resolve this.

The only thing I have not tried is rebooting the server--which is impractical because this is a production server.

Comment: Check the parent process.

Answer (score 2):

First, try send it `SIGSTOP` to actually stop its execution (this may be trapped and ignored by the command, but worth trying).

Next, this looks suspicious.
Since any process is free to change the text which is shown in the process list (some programs such as MTAs do this all the time for legitimate purposes), so it *might* be that your machine was p0wned and that proces is not really `find` but something else (such as a crypto miner).

There are several ways to try to inspect what it really is.

1. Try looking at what executable it is:

   ```
    # stat /proc/$pid/exe
   ```

   Should show you what binary executable is running in that process.
2. Watching filesystem activity of that process might help:

   ```
   # watch vdir /proc/$pid/fd
   ```

   If it's really appears as opening and closing lots of
   files, it's probably really `find`.
3. The process must not have any sockets open (viewable at the same `/proc/$pid/fd` hierarchy.
4. You may `strace` it and see whether it indeed repeatedly
   opens and closes directories — run

   ```
   # strace -p $pid
   ```

   and watch for `opendir` and `fdopendir` syscalls.
5. Check out [`debsums`](https://packages.debian.org/debsums).

Comment: kill -SIGSTOP did not work.  :-(

The stat command indicated that /usr/bin/find was indeed the command.  the watch of vdir did not net much...just 5 entries, three of which were /dev/pts/2\ and marked as (deleted).  strace did not show anything for 10 minutes.

Comment: @Eriks, OK, so you may try to install `gdb` and `kill` it after attaching to the PID of your running `find` process. See [this](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_76.html) for more info.